# Update/refresh listview in a fragment & custom adapter

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, refresh, fragment

What do I need to call from Fragment 1 to force an update/refresh of Fragment 2 when Fragment 2 has code in `onActivityCreated()` to load the data, create a custom array adapter and set it on a ListView?

Is there a way to update/refresh the ListView or is the intent to `Replace()` the Fragment to force it to be rebuilt and rerun the code in `onActivityCreated()`?

Here is a snipped of the Fragment 2 onActivityCreated() code:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      // Get the prepared data and load it into this view
      ArrayList<ReportData> oReportResultsData = Report.LoadData(Home.ScheduleJSonData,         Home.SelectedDate);

      //Set the list into the gridview (Listview formatted with rows/columns)
      ScheduledActivityReportGridArrayAdapter myGridArrayAdapter = new         ScheduledActivityReportGridArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.homeschedulerow, oReportResultsData);
      lstReport.setAdapter(myGridArrayAdapter);
    }
```

I did try to manually call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the Fragment Manager in hopes that would force it to reload/refresh Fragment 2.  I have reread the docs and many great answers out here but the custom `LoadData()` method and custom adapter being setup in `onActivityCreated()` I've not see addressed.

Many Thanks!

Comment: was this ever resolved? I'm facing a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

Your fragments should communicate with each other through the Activity, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity.

Your first fragment should call a method on the activity, which in turn calls another method on the second fragment, which will then reload your data.